# 3 travelers and 9 diamonds

Tags: logical-deduction, meta-knowledge

There are **three travelers**. They are inside a cave. Deep down in this cave, there are **three doors**, each door containing **at least one diamond**, and there are a total of **9 diamonds**. Each traveler picks a door and gets the diamonds behind it.

The travelers loot their diamonds, and, before exiting the cave, all three must say **simultaneously** if they can deduce the number of diamonds that each of the other two have. They never lie, and **all of them said they couldn't deduce it**.

After these statements were said, one of the travelers realized that now he knows the answer.

So the question is:

> How were the diamonds split between the three travelers? (**the order doesn't matter**)

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! May I ask where you found this riddle?

Comment: I have a question : When one of the travelers knew the answer, did he say that out loud? @AtAn

Comment: Yes. sorry, I thought that was explicit enough.

Comment: I've heard of a variation where there is only one case where no one can deduce the answer immediately. However, this problem seems to have multiple ambiguous cases.

Comment: You're sure this is possible and your teacher isn't playing some kind of trick, right?

Comment: Yes, I'm 100% sure.

Comment: wait, so did the travelers say it out loud that he knows the answer or not? @AtAn

Comment: [This](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/55510/five-hats-and-three-logicians) is the variation I was referring to, but I don't think you can use the same strategy.

Comment: They say it out loud.

Comment: These hat puzzles are indeed similar. I've tried their approach to solve this diamond's problem.

Comment: Does a traveler have to know which of the other two have what number? For example if a traveler has 6, can he immediately deduce the other two have 1 and 2 (without specifying which has which)?

Comment: Yes he can immediately deduce. I think that's what OP means by "the order doesn't matter".

Comment: @sedrick That is correct.

Comment: Has your professor given you the "correct" answer to this riddle yet?  If so, is it worth posting as a self-answer?

Answer (score 13):

I think it isn't possible and here is my reasoning.

> First we know that nobody has 6 or 7 because they could immediately deduce the other two.
>
>  Now let's analyze this from the perspective of the traveler who figured it out. Here are the possibilities given the number he knows.
>
>  1: 35, 44
>  2: 25, 34
>  3: 15, 24, 33
>  4: 14, 23
>  5: 13, 22
>
>   The only way a traveler could figure out the quantities later is if there was only one combination but all possibilities have 2 or 3. Therefore I don't think it's possible.

Comment: Note that you didn't discard the repeated ones (135 and 513, 144 and 414, etc). If you didn't because you're analyzing one's traveler outcome then it is fine, but at this point we don't get anything from it...

Answer (score 5):

Someone has shown why the puzzle does not seem to have a solution. however...

> maybe your professor gave this puzzle to you in writing, and also has bad handwriting, and wrote an 8 which looked like a 9. which is not totally implausible. however I don't know whether they actually gave it to you in writing.

like with other analyses, we can rule out a few possibilites:

> we know that no traveller can have 6, because they would deduce the others have 1 each, and also not 5, since then they would deduce the others have 1 and 2.
>
>  from here, every traveller has between 1 and 4 diamonds, and knows this of each other traveller, and nows the diamonds sum to 8
>
>  when a traveller has a number of diamonds, there are only a few possibilities for what the other travellers hold, due to the summing to 8.
>
>  I list the possibilities here
>
>
>  4: 13, 22
>  3: 23, 14
>  2: 24, 33
>  1: 34
>
>  1 only has 1 possibility for what the other travellers hold, which means that the solution was deduced by a traveller who looted 1 diamond

Answer (score 4):

Warning: Skewey logic ahead.

First off:

> If you have 6 or 7 diamonds, you know that the combination is `1,1,7` or `1,2,6` right away.

Now, since no one said that, it's clearly not true.  However:

> The only time that this gives you *new* information is if you have either 1 or 2 diamonds

This means:

> Anyone who looks *interested* in that fact has either 1 or 2 diamonds - but they still don't know how many the other people have

This means that someone *else* has to make a guess:

> Now knowing that at least 1 person has either 1 or 2 diamonds:
>  If they have 5 diamonds, then the combinations available are `1,3,5` with 1 interested person or `2,2,5` with 2 interested people
>  If they have 4 diamonds, then the combinations available are `1,4,4` with 1 interested person, or `2,3,4` also with 1 interested person
>  If they have 3 diamonds, then the combinations available are `1,3,5` with 1 interested person, or `2,3,4` also with 1 interested person
>  If they have 2 diamonds, then the only combination available is `2,2,5` with 1 other interested person
>  If they have 1 diamond, then no one else will show any interest - so we discount this option

Since we know that someone **must** make a correct guess here, we know that

> The guesser does not have 1, 3, or 4 diamonds

Meaning

> The combinations are `1,3,5` or `2,2,5`

Furthermore!  We know that **one** person guesses, hence:

> The combination is `1,3,5`, and the guesser is the person with 5 diamonds, because if the combination was `2,2,5` then *everyone* would be able to guess it at this point.

Comment: Your solution seems compelling, but I don't know what you mean by "interested person".

Comment: @AtAn There are 3 cases going into the first declaration:  You know what the numbers are, you don't know what the numbers are, and you know that no one knows what the numbers are.  After everyone says "I don't know", everyone in the second group moves to the third, and has to re-think based on that information - the new fact is of interest to them.  Anyone already in the third group will not show any interest in the fact, as it was already known to them.  (i.e. the 3rd spoiler)

Comment: how does someone determine that someone else is "interested" in the fact that no one has 6 or 7?

Comment: @SilverCookie Facial expressions / [cold reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_reading)?  If their reaction to finding out that no one knows how many diamonds they each have is to fall into deep thought, then they must not have already known/realised that that was going to be the case.  (As other answers have pointed out, we need at least 1 more piece of info to answer the puzzle - I just tried to come up with one you could determine by observing the other )

Comment: @ ok I understand your point

Comment: I can confirm there is no lateral thinking or some tricky thing in this puzzle. Can you explain to me why "the only time that this gives you new information is if you have either 1 or 2 diamonds"? I still didn't catch your logic behind this. Also, if the traveler who guesses has 1 or 2 diamonds (or else he wouldn't have this new information), why do you conclude that he has 5 diamonds?

Comment: @AtAn If you have 6 or 7 diamonds, you know how many diamonds there are.  If you have 3, 4 or 5 diamonds, then **you know that no one else has 6 or 7 diamonds**.  If you have 2 diamonds, you know that no one has 7 diamonds, and if you have 1 diamond then you're pretty much clueless.  When everyone says "I don't know", it tells you that no one has 6 or 7 diamonds - **but**, if you have 3, 4 or 5 diamonds then you *already* knew that.  Hence, only people with 1 or 2 diamonds learn anything new at that point.

Comment: Great, I've tried that kind of reasoning as well but didn't get very far. However, this way, shouldn't you have 2 diamonds? That would explain you figuring it out, as you gained more information about the others's quantities. I'm not 100% sure if the problem states that none of the others figured out as well after knowing that no one knows, but that's likely the case and, with this, the distribution should be 2 for the guesser (the only with more information) and 3 and 4 for the others (they couldn't deduce).

Comment: @AtAn If you check Spoiler 4, then you'll see why someone with 2 diamonds would still have 2 possible combinations available to them.  The "trick" is that you gain new information by observing reactions of people who suddenly realise that *they* have new information - allowing you to identify people who have either 1 or 2 diamonds.  (i.e.  the first "new" information is "no one has 6 or 7 diamonds".  The *second* new information is "to whom was the first information new?", a.k.a. "who has 1 or 2 diamonds")

Comment: We may as well assume no one got new information because no one ever said so. There aren't really 2 possible combinations - it seems that the only one that results in 1 guesser and 2 clueless travelers is 2, 3, 4. With 2, 2, 4, we have 3 clueless travelers. Same if the guesser had only 1; he would be, in fact, clueless. We know that only he figured it out, so **it can't be the case that he has only 1 diamond**. There would be too many possibilities. If he guessed it, the distribution *must* be 2, 3, 4. (I may be entering a rabbit hole here with all this, please take a look at my take on it).

Comment: @AtAn We know that *someone* got new information, because we've been told in the question that they then worked out how many diamonds there were.  Just knowing that "no one has 6 or 7" doesn't make the answer possible, so there must be additional information from somewhere - hence the assumption in Spoiler 4 that at least one non-guesser has 1 or 2 diamonds (which means that the guesser can't have 1 diamond, because they would be the only person who did)  It's like the the "nobody smiled" in [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/55510/five-hats-and-three-logicians)

Answer (score 1):

If the one guy is a little slow then...

> <del>The one person who knows received seven diamonds, and the other two each received one.  I have no explanation for why the traveler with seven couldn't immediately figure this out.</del> The one person who knows received six diamonds, and one other person received one, and another received two.

Comment: Well, that's  not possible because they couldn't deduce the quantity at first right?

Comment: Yeah, it seems unlikely that this is the answer a math professor is going for.  I'm seeing if I can work something better out.

Comment: Yup, I just posted my answer (I think I may be wrong also) :)

Comment: @Kevin L is right; they couldn't deduce.

Comment: Isn't this the same. They still couldn't deduce

Answer (score 1):

I think I may have the solution (I hope)

I will write down all the possibilities first :

> 117 126 135 144 153 162 171 
>  216 225 234 243 252 261 
>  315 324 333 342 351 
>  414 423 432 441 
>  513 522 531 
>  612 621 
>  711

From this, I will only write the numbers that don't have similar numbers with different arrangements :

> 333

As you can see, this is the only possibility where the travelers will be able to know the number of diamonds because it is the only number with a unique arrangement

Comment: Can you explain why 3,3,3 is easier to figure out than 3,2,4?

Comment: @AtAn is this the answer u had in mind or am I completely off track :D ?

Comment: @Reibello Well because 324 has other similar numbers with different arrangements (342, 423, 432)

Comment: How is that so? What if it is distributed as 5-2-2? None of them could figure out as well. In what way can the arrangement reveal the answer?

Comment: @AtAn u said that in the end, one of them figured it out so it has to be a number that doesn't have other similar numbers with different arrangements. 522 has other numbers like 225 and 252 right?

Comment: But how does the traveler know that?

Comment: Order doesn't matter I take to mean "126=162=216=261=612=621", so your argument doesn't hold. Also in say "144" the first traveller could possibly deduce the others' diamonds since there is no ordering in "44"

Comment: @Reibello Now that I can't answer :D

Comment: I think you're assuming that the travelers know the quantities envolved. They don't. Why the answer shouldn't have different arrangements?

Comment: Hmm, I'm starting to think that this is actually impossible

Comment: No i think it means "sum up" to 9

Comment: Wait the answer should have different arrangements right so that one of the guys could figure out the quantities @AtAn

Comment: There are 9 total diamonds. No more, no less. We want to know how many diamonds each of them got, regardless of the order.

Answer (score 1):

The statements:

- all three say **simultaneously**,

> so noone has any information before they call it. and

- they couldn't deduce it.

> with their own diamond.

moreover,

- each door containing **at least one diamond**.

so There are a few possibilities for their loots:

> | $1,1,7$ |, | $1,2,6$ |, | $1,3,5$ |, | $1,4,4$ |, | $2,2,5$ |, | $2,3,4$ |, |3,3,3|

and out of these, we can easily eliminate some of them since noone could deduce the number of diamonds;

> | $1,1,7$ | -> If this was the case, whoever had 7 diamonds would figure out the number of diamonds for each person since at least one diamond per person and only 2 diamonds are left to be divided into two people.

and after they said they could not

> "*one of the travelers **realized** that he knew the answer*". Actually he/she knew the answer but could not realize before they all call for it. So he didnt lie just he could deduce the number of the diamonds of others, but he realized it after they call for their deduction. Sometimes you know the answer, but you could not realize it before something happens.

so the answer is actually

> **| $1,1,7$ |**

Comment: They all know there are 9 diamonds. If one picked up 7 diamonds, then there's only 2 left, 1 for each of the others. This way he would've said he could deduce, when exiting.

Comment: @AtAn I think u didnt read my explanation. you say "he realizes", not "then he knows" ... "one of the travelers **realized that he knew the answer**."

Comment: Ok, I'm editing the post. I put it that way to make it less clear that the fact of none of them knowing the answer is crucial to the puzzle. He didn't knew the answer before saying.

Answer (score 1):

> The traveller who realized the answer did 9 minus the sum of the two numbers other traveller said. You know your quantity, you know how many the other is missing, so you can figure out the third one (if you didn't pay attention to what he said). That's how he knew the answer. Otherwise you can't know the specific combination. You can only know the answer after the statements are made.

EDIT:
Fixed spoiler

Comment: You don't know the quantities involved. That's what you're trying to figure out.

Comment: What do you mean? Don't they know there are 9 diamonds in total?

Comment: Yes. But you gotta find how many diamonds each traveler has.

Comment: I know. I'm saying it's impossible unless someone takes a guess first.

Comment: Unless... rot13(Gurl nyy cvpx gur fnzr qbbe).

Comment: This isn't the case... also, if they all knew it, they would've said it as well when exiting.