# Move one shape in the equation

Tags: mathematics

$1484 / (7 / 9) = 19$

Make the equation true by moving one continuous shape or operation in the equation.

Comment: “Most creative” runs the risk of being too broad or primarily opinion-based. For that reason I’d argue that it’s not a very good criterion to judge potential answers to a puzzle.

Comment: @El-Guest Is this appropriate for SE Puzzling?

Comment: Rohit, I have voted to reopen this new question as written. It appears to be less opinion-based now.

Comment: After the edit, there's no longer an $x$, and the two existing answers now have no relation to the question.

Comment: @El-Guest me too :P

Comment: If you can *fix* this question, please do so.  But don’t just make it a copy of [your other question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/72099/19765) and [your other question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/72289/19765).

Comment: @Peregrine Rook I have, but it’s still not reopened and I’ve been told to just make another one

Answer (score 3):

This is just

> $x = 250 \times 45 = 11250.$ where you can put the decimal point at the end of a number I believe.

Comment: Hmmm, good, it works, but I'm looking for CREATIVITY. Good start though.

Comment: @RohitJose That is what I originally stated in [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/71707/make-1-dots-15-using-3-9-9-9) puzzle of mine, but risked being closed as too broad :\

Comment: Well, I guess I'll risk it as well!

Comment: @El-Guest I have changed the question. Please edit or delete your answer