# Move one thing in the equation

Tags: mathematics

$1484 / (7 / 9) = 19$

Make the equation true by moving one continuous shape or operation in the equation.

Comment: What do you mean by *continuous shape*?

Comment: @Wais Kamal however you interpret it!

Comment: -1 until the directions become more clear on what is expressly allowed.

Comment: @user1717828 They are there: no inequality or equality signs, and no messing with the = sign

Comment: @RohitJose There are multiple distinct answers that fit those rules.

Comment: I've found multiple ways to make the left side equal 18, but I'm having difficulty finding 19.

Comment: Are you looking for an actual mathematical answer as opposed to a clever answer?

Comment: @maxathousand all of them use the = sign or make an inequality sign or a equality sign

Comment: @tox123 I’m looking for a clever answer that is still somewhat mathematical

Comment: Is there a valid solution in this puzzle?

Comment: I notice that $154/(7/9) = 198$ moving the $8$. I can't seem to progress with this idea though. I wonder if anyone can help?

Comment: @RohitJose I count 5 answers that leave the equals sign untouched. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: By *continuous shape*, do you mean a contiguous black shape? Not a region containing multiple separate black shapes? Is it acceptable to change numbers into other numbers by overlaying lines on them? Is it acceptable to break a shape and move only part of it? Is grouping/parentheses considered a single operation (I mean, can you freely move *both* parentheses around, or must any movement just be one parenthesis?). I've been staring at this for way too long...

Comment: Closest I've gotten (before the hint), was $14\cdot4/(7/9) = 19 \text{ }\text{ } \text{ }  8$, (where the 8 on the right is missing a middle dot). The left side is 72, which is $9\cdot8$, but I couldn't figure out how to assemble that on the right side. Ah well.

Comment: @Justin "*[however you interpret it!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72099/move-one-thing-in-the-equation/72114?noredirect=1#comment215656_72099)*"... 

Comment: Are we allow to rewrite the equation in the first place such as 1484*(9/7) = 19?

Comment: @Alex Well you are technically switching 2 things around, so no

Comment: Got it! Writing it up now, but it contradicts your hint - it moves a digit. But that's still ok, right? Even if it's not the one you are thinking?

Comment: @RohitJose it seems like you are adding rules to each answer as they are being posted. Please clearly state **all** the rules in the question.

Comment: @R.D these are the FINAL rules

Comment: I think I have to downvote - the rules keep changing, and even though there has been a series of answers that met the rules at the time, you've changed the rules to make them invalid. This has become a game of "guess what I am thinking" not "find a valid answer".

Comment: @eedrah Why? These are the FINAL rules

Comment: The question is already 2 days old and has 14 answers submitted - I feel it's too late to be changing the question.

I would suggest choosing the answer that fits best the unedited answer, and then posting a new question with your edited rules.

Comment: I think I’ll do that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a similar method to [Vaelus' answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/72112/41731), take the

> empty space above the equation connecting the 8 and the second `/`, like so:
>
>  [image: step 1]

EDIT: The continuous shape that I've extracted is given by the blue here, which fits the requirements of the original question:

> [image: step 2]

If you then

> rotate this 135 degrees clockwise, you will see that the slash is now vertical and looks like a 1, and the 8 looks like two diagonal zeros
>
>  [image: step 3]

Either

> shrink this

or

> change the distance of the two pieces from the viewer to simulate zooming. It will look like the following:
>
>  [image: step 4]
>
>  Superimpose this back on the remainder to get this:
>
>  [image: step 5]

Which gives us

> the modulo operator, and the equation
>  `1441 % (79) = 19`

Which is true

Comment: Wouldn't this be considered moving two things?

Comment: Yes, that is moving two things

Comment: I've added another image to show that this meets the requirements of the question, by "moving one continuous shape". It is moving two glyphs, but they are connected by a continuous shape.

Comment: This is the correct answer?

Comment: @Robert S. If you read the last comment on the original post you’ll understand

Answer (score 22):

> If you move the continuous region of background outlined in red to the indicated location:
>  
>  [image]
>
>
>  The equation becomes true:
>
> [image]

Comment: Hahhah, this made me laugh. Very creative

Comment: Wow... that’s  unbelievable... I never thought of that

Comment: I like the circuit board.  Nice touch

Comment: I don't get this answer, is the slash supposed to represent a slanted one?

Comment: @AnthonyPham Yes, although it's certainly not good style. I don't know what the author was thinking.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe

> Take the first(or second) slash/division and put over the equal sign(that's what everyone else does).

To get

> 1484(7/9)≠19

If this is allowed :p

Comment: Nooooo! Not that! UGHHH! Do I have to specify this every time I make something like this?

Comment: For what it’s worth, I officially approve of this answer haha!

Comment: I think you meant to write **second**.

Comment: Sure that would work too :)

Comment: "Do I have to specify this every time I make something like this?" Only if you want to ask a community that tries its hardest to bend the rules... I mean think laterally to get an answer.

Comment: @Alpha I know... I know...

Answer (score 7):

> Move the $1$ in $1484$ and move it to cross the $1$ in $19$.
>
>  $484 / (7 / 9) = x9$
>
>  The solution to this equation is $x = 484/7$.

---

> **UPDATE:** In response to the hint (I'm sure this is still not the answer OP is wanting, however, it fits the rules just fine), the same trick can be done by moving either of the division signs.
>
>  $1484 (7 / 9) = x9$; Solution: $x = 10388/81$
>  or
>  $1484 / (79) = x9$; Solution: $x = 1484/711$

Comment: This is interesting, but not right because you haven’t defined the x, so you don’t know if it’s correct

Comment: @RohitJose Did I misinterpret any of the rules? There seems to be many valid answers...

Comment: @RohitJose An equation is a statement that the values of two mathematical expressions are equal ([source](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+equation)). This is, by definition, an equation, just as $a = b$ is an equation.

Comment: but is it true?

Comment: I may be speaking out of my expertise here, but I don't believe it's possible to call an equation that includes an algebraic expression true or false. If you mean "solvable", then yes, there exists a solution for which $484/(7/9) = x9$ is true. All of this really is irrelevant to solving your puzzle, as you've already indicated this is not the answer you have in mind. Would you consider adding a hint to narrow down the possible answers?

Comment: This should help. Look at the question now

Comment: In the absence of prior knowns about $x$, any equation involving $x$ would only be true if it were assumed to be true. If you have the assumption $4 x = 5$, then you can say $x = \frac{5}{4}$ is true by consequence, but $4 x = 5$ is only considered true because we assume it to be true.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative solution...

> Take the $=$ sign and spin it 90 degrees to make it into a logical OR operator $||$. Thus, the resulting expression is: $1484/(7/9) || 19$ which equates to TRUE since both sides of the || are not equal to $0$.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! I would imagine that this falls under the "no inequality signs" rule, which is designed to prevent exactly these sorts of sneaky answers.

Comment: Wow I didn’t think of that! Well done, but as above, no cheaty answers

Comment: I don't think this is making an inequality sign.  If OP doesn't want someone touching the `=` he should expressly disallow moving or modifying it.

Comment: Done. How’s that then?

Answer (score 5):

I'm sure this isn't what you want either:

> Assuming rotation is allowed, move the second division sign over to the equals sign and make it "defined as".

Like:

> 1484/(79) ≡ 19.  Not sure why you'd want to define it this way though...

Comment: Good idea, but not correct

Answer (score 5):

I think if

> The equation was formed like $1484 / (\frac 7{9}) = 19$

We could

> Move a copy of $\frac 7{9}$ over the $84$ to make it $14\frac 7{9} / (\frac 7{9}) = 19$

Comment: That's an interesting idea, but incorrect

Answer (score 4):

Well, I'm sure this isn't the correct answer; however, if you round up!

> 14(84/7/9) = 18.6... rounded up = 19.

Comment: Good, but no rounding

Comment: If you leave a down-vote, please comment and explain how I can improve my post.

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure this is not what you want either, but

> if you take the bottom line of the equal sign and tilt it upward, you make an awkward greater than sign and $1484/(7/9)>19$ is true.

Comment: xhienne tried this already, but good try

Comment: @RohitJose SteveV was first to propose an inequality. But this one is different.

Comment: No equalities as well

Answer (score 4):

Take the

> First division sign

and use it to

> strikethrough the 4, 8, and 7

to get

> $1$<strike>484(7/</strike>$9)$$=19$

Or

> $19=19$

SOLUTION #2
Re-read the title.

The 'thing' i'm putting in the equation is

> 08, at the end.

Which is

> $1484/(7/9)$ $=$ $1908$

Math:

> $1484/(7/9)$ --> $(1484*9)/7$ --> $1908$

Comment: The ROT13(svefg qvivfvba fvta) is not that long!

Comment: Good idea, but what about the dots? Also, yes, as Wais Kamal said, it’s not THAT long

Comment: Oh yea. Right. Back to the drawing board with more CREATIVE solutions

Comment: I see where you're going with the second solution, but "08" would not be considered a continuous shape since the two numbers are separated.

Comment: Seriously? Sigh.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to agree with Robert

Answer (score 3):

A similar idea as others who have fiddled with the equal sign:

> move the second `/` over the equal sign in order to make a `≤` sign
>
>  This yields: $1484/(79) ≤ 19$
>
>  (which is correct since 1484 / 79 ~= 18.78)

Comment: This would require two moves, so I don't think it qualifies.

Comment: No @RobertS, the equal sign doesn't change despite what the font is displaying.

Comment: Also, he said no inequality signs altogether.

Comment: Also, the problem is to make a true *equation*

Comment: You may be right @Robert, I thought OP was only referring to the one used in [QuantumTwinkie's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/72100/32339). I'll wait for a comment from the author, though, as I'm unsure.

Comment: @RohitJose That seems unfair then. Now this puzzle has devolved into a "guess what I'm thinking" game.

Comment: @maxathousand Ok, let me rephrase, as seen now in the question, no messing with the = sign

Comment: @RohitJose - People just can't stop fiddling with your equality sign.

Answer (score 2):

If we could

> take the slanty bit off the top of the first 4

We are left with

> 1 + 84 / (7/9) = 19

and we can

> place a single straight line somewhere

to make it all work out.

But

> 1 + 84/(7/9) = 109

and I can't find a way to

> turn 19 into 109 by adding a single straight line

(or any other way to proceed down this line of thinking)

Comment: You are not on the right track, but good try

Comment: You can even get to the same place by removing the first 4 entirely. The left hand side 1 84/(7/9) could arguably be considered implicit multiplication by 1 or addition of 1 like a strange mixed fraction, to get 108 or 109. I can't figure out how to use a 4 on the right hand side either though.

Answer (score 2):

If you

> lasso a region containing the two 1s and move them both down a bit, you end up with
>
>  $1^{484/(7/9)} = 1^9$

Each side just simplifies to get

> $1 = 1$

Comment: Good answer, but that moves 2 ones. Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Also, the hint says "don't move a digit" so, yeah.

Comment: It moves 2 ones, but by the same amount, and you could easily define a single region containing only them. Seems just as legitimate as the accepted answer to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply move the

> second division sign to connect the tail of the 9 to the bottom of the circle of the 9, making the 9 into an 8.
>
>
> As a result, the equation is now
>  $$1484 / (78) = 19$$
>
>  As long as we use the computer science `/` operator, namely floored division, the equation is true.

Comment: Good try, but I was meaning that to be the division operator, the floor operator is //