# Move something in the equation

Tags: mathematics

$1484 / (7 / 9) = 19$

Make the equation true by moving one continuous shape or operation in the equation.

(You are NOT allowed to make an inequality or equality sign or touch the = sign.)

You can‘t move or touch a digit, or make variables.

Comment: I have posted another question like this, but this is with different rules

Answer (score 1):

1484/(7/9)=19?

> Just remove division in between 7 & 9 ---> 1484/(79)= 18.7848101266

or

> If you consider 14.84/(7/9) = 19.08

Comment: The question says "move" (not "remove") and also 18.784... is not equal to 19. Good job though.

Comment: Thanks. I know 18.78 not equal to 19, but I tried many operations but I haven't get exact 19

Comment: yup, it's not, but it's definitely close. I'm sure that there's a "more exact" solution though.

Answer (score 1):

An idle thought...

> // can be a floor division operator in some contexts (e.g. Python). OP's profile happens to mention their interest in Python as well. Alas, 1484 // (79) = 18, so it's close but no cigar.